# How to create a table in swift with segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm brand new to Swift but I want to create an app that has a table and each entry in that table will lead to a new screen (but this new screen is the same for all the table entries) but depending on which table cell you click on, that screen has different information posted on it.

What are the steps I need to do to complete this? I have my story board I'm just not sure how to put this all together with code
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is very broad and not very specific. Therefore it is not easy to give a helpful answer. What I would do:

1. **Create** a UITableViewController that holds your "table".
2. **Define** a UITableViewControllerDelegate for the UITableView that will be informed about UserInteractions (especially when the user
   *didSelect* a certain row of the table).
3. Based on the specific row (that was selected) you can **create** a second UIViewController class the shows your intended information.

I can not show some code samples because your question is to broad and things depend on a lot of things (especially on the kind of data you want to show) and how you implement your UIElements on the ViewControllers in InterfaceBuilder.

And if you are not yet familiar with the concept of a UITableViewController and its Delegate, than you should find some tutorials first about that basic technique in developing iOS apps.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the master/detail pattern. I suggest doing a search on that.